# How can I have a JFrame with a JComboBox over a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Basically I'm try to add a dropdown to my code here. Although whenever I try to add one after the other, it ends up overtaking it. If I run the dropdown before the scroll then I get the scroll on top and vice versa. I'm kinda new to JFrames and drawing in Java so please bear with me.

MyFrame Class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JViewport;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    public void cadetImage() throws FontFormatException, IOException {

        JPanel panel = new Puller();
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(panel, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        String[] opts = { "All", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
        JComboBox<String> dropdown = new JComboBox<>(opts);

        setTitle("Puller");
        scroll.getViewport().setScrollMode(JViewport.SIMPLE_SCROLL_MODE);
        add(dropdown, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setSize(500, 500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    }
}
```

Puller Class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Puller extends JPanel {

    private int pw, ph;
    private Font rso;

    public Puller() throws FontFormatException, IOException {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("assets/fonts/racing sans one.ttf");
        Dimension screen = new Dimension(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        pw = (int) screen.getWidth();
        ph = (int) screen.getHeight();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(pw - 20, ph - 30));

        rso = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics p) {
        Graphics2D page = (Graphics2D) p;

        template(page);
    }

    private void template(Graphics2D page) {
        page.setColor(Color.decode("#666666"));
        page.fillRect(0, 0, pw, ph);

        // Name Header
        page.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        page.fillRect(997, 122, 311, 90);
        page.setColor(Color.decode("#bf9000"));
        page.fillRect(1000, 125, 305, 84);
        page.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        page.setFont(rso.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 75f));
        page.drawString("NAME", 1052, 193);

        // Filter Field
        page.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        page.fillRect(997, 212, 70, 50);
        page.setColor(Color.decode("#666666"));
        page.fillRect(1000, 212, 64, 47);
    }
}
```

Whatever help I can get would be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't the combobox be "inside" the `JScrollPane`, which would suggest you need to add it the `Puller` pane?

Comment: `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(pw - 20, ph - 30));` - no, on so many fronts.  Use `JFrame#setExtendedState` instead, as you're making no allowance for the actual visible/usable range of the screen - does it have dock bar?  Does it have task bar? Does it have system menu? Don't override `paint` as a general preference, prefer `paintComponent`, it's far less complicated and less likely you'll completely screw up the painting process by accident

Comment: `BorderLayout` only manages a single component at each of it's 5 available locations, so you can't have two components at the same location, `BorderLayout` will only manage the last one added.  The question then becomes, what does "over the scroll pane" actually mean?  I mean, if you add the combobox to the `Puller` pane, then you'd have a combobox "over" the scroll pane (or at least on top visiually)